# how to stop rerendering in react on checkbox check?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple `list` which is dynamically added on `add` button click. in my list there is a `checkbox` is also present .so I have an issue when I toggle the checkbox my whole list is re render why ?

let take example I added `A`,`B`,`C`,`D` in my list when I toggle `D` checkbox it should only render `D` item currently it render whole list why ?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wildflower-gv9be

```
const Item = ({ text, checked, onCheckedHandler }) => {
  console.log(checked, "ssss");
  return (
    <div className={checked ? "bg" : ""}>
      <span>{text}</span>
      <input type="checkbox" onChange={e => onCheckedHandler(e, text)} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time `items` changes (whether by adding a new item or checking a value), you are creating a new `onCheckedHandler` in your `App`. This propagates down to your `Item` component. Since the previous `onCheckedHandler` property is not referentially equivalent to the previous one, it renders (and you see that console log for each item). Memoizing the component alone won't help because a property being passed to it is changing every time.

To get around that, you need to memoize the `onCheckedHandler`, try this:

```
const onCheckedHandler = useCallback((e, selectedText) => {
  const target = e.target
  setItems(items => {
    const i = items.findIndex(i => i.text === selectedText);
    let obj = items[i];
    obj.checked = target.checked;
    return [...items.slice(0, i), obj, ...items.slice(i + 1)];
  })
}, [setItems])
```

The you can wrap your `Item` compoennt with `React.memo`, and it should work as expected. You'll also need to import the `useCallback` the same way you import `useState`

Comment: but still `React.memo` help ..if i remove `react.memo` still rerendering many times

Comment: Correct, sorry, I must have been playing with a version that already memoized it (and what why I put my comment about why React.memo wasn't enough). I updated my answer to be more complete,